# Why does float() work differently on + and /?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, division

```
float(5.5 + 1) # returns 6.5
float(5.5) + 1 # also returns 6.5


float(11 / 2) # returns 5
float(11) / 2 # returns 5.5
```

Why does `float` work differently in this example?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is caused by the operator and types of operands, `float` doesn't have anything to do with it.

`/` performs integer division in Python 2, if both operands are integers. So

```
>>> 11 / 2
5
```

Then `float(5)` is `5.0`.

If at least one operand is a `float`, `/` will perform float division:

```
>>> float(11) / 2 # == 11.0 / 2
5.5
```

See [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Answer (score 0):

```
float(11 / 2)
```

This first evaluate `11/2`, which is 5 (as both are integer, division result will be an integer), then coverts it to float which is 5.0

```
float(11) / 2
```

This converts 11 to float first which is 11.0 and then divide by 2. `11.0/2=5.5`, (as one of them are float, division result will be a float) exactly what you are getting.

Comment: But why does 0.5 + 1 return the same as float(0.5) + 1? The 0.5 hasnt been converted to float yet.

Comment: @Ch3wbacc4  0.5 is float already. try this : `print type(0.5)`

Comment: Try '11/2'. Then try '11.0/2'

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x division of integers returns an integer. You need to cast one of the operands to a float e.g. `float (11.0 / 2)`. You can also import the division behaviour of Python 3.x to 2.x using `from __future__ import division`.

Moreover, `//` always means floor division on both 2.x and 3.x.